# How to properly manage the sending of so many different bulk e-mails to the entire user base?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, email

One of my PHP/MySQL sites is a social network and I need to send many different e-mails, including:

1) **Event-based:** E-mails sent when a specific action occurs on a user's account to notify them about it (they received a new message on the site, somebody friended them, someone posted on their wall, etc).

2) **Periodic:** E-mails sent on a regular basis (e.g a weekly list of people they might know sent every Saturday, a monthly Newsletter discussing the new features of the site, a fortnightly list of new users in their area, etc.).

With hundreds of thousands of users, how in the world do you manage the sending of so much e-mail, to so many users?  How do you ensure the e-mails don't get blocked by ISP's?  How do you handle the unsubscriptions with so many different e-mail categories?  How do you personalize the e-mails for each user?  How do you ensure users don't get bombarded with too many e-mails within a 1-day, 7-day, and 30-day period?  How do I integrate this into my existing site?

I have an Amazon SES account with 100,000 daily / 28 per second send limits.

How can I use Amazon SES to handle all of the above?  It sounds incredibly overwhelming!

**EDIT:**

Since some are interpreting my question as asking SO to design an e-mail management system for me and downvoting the question as a result, let me be clearer:  **Is there an existing PHP/MySQL script that can handle my needs above and integrate with Amazon SES and an existing site?**  Or would I need to design such an E-mail Management System from scratch?

Comment: way too broad and way too many questions.

Comment: @MarcB: How can a question on how to manage bulk e-mail in PHP/MySQL using Amazon SES be a broad question?  Please explain.

Comment: sounds like a system i want to avoid...

Comment: you're basically asking us to give you the design for a bulk email system with spam handling. That's every so slightly too much to ask for a free help site. we're here to help, not do YOUR job for you.

Comment: you have 7 questions in here - maybe more. and you show no code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: @MarcB: So you're saying there is **no** PHP/MySQL script that manages bulk e-mail and can be easily integrated into an existing site?

Comment: @Randy: The questions are there to indicate the types of issues I'm dealing with.  I can't be the first to come upon this problem, as I've seen several large sites with millions of users that have about 8 different categories of e-mails they send out to their user base (all of them individually unsubscribable).  I find it hard to believe that everyone who comes upon this problem is forced to design an e-mail management system from scratch.

Comment: no idea. never looked for one. sending/customizing emails isn't exactly hard. it's PHP.. a templating engine. sending email isn't horribly different from generating an html page, after all.

Comment: @MarcB: "no idea. never looked for one."  Yet your immediate impulse is to Close this question when you have absolutely no idea if there is a script other SO's users have used successfully that might do just what I'm looking for?  I think you jumped the gun on this one if you have no idea about what I'm asking, to be fair.

Comment: No, I voted to close because you're asking too many overly-broad questions. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask   "if you can imagine an entire book..."

Comment: @MarcB: Again, as I mentioned to Randy, I'm not expecting answers to those questions, I posed them to give users an idea of the issues I'm facing and to give specific context rather than just a broad "I need an e-mail management system".  I still think you jumped the gun downvoting a question when you don't know anything about the topic at hand.  At any rate, I've added an edit to my question so others don't misinterpret me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My implementation would be to give each user a UserID # (if you haven't already), and then I would have 2 tables (well, 2 main user tables).  The first would be something like users_main where you store their basic info, UID, name, email, etc, etc, etc, and I would make one of those fields 'notify' which would be a simple boolean True False, True meaning they do want to receive event based notifications, and false meaning they do not.  The reason for including this in the main database is because you're going to need their info if they do want to get an email, so you'll already have their info cached.

The second table would be users_periodic or some such.  This is literally just a list of UIDs who want to get the newsletter, along with any info you need to send it (for example the columns might be UID, email, name).  Then when you make your query, just select all rows from this table.  Makes your database lookups a little easier.

Ideally, I believe you would run two separate servers/databases, because when this runs, it's going to suck up your entire I/O til it's done, which is fine if that's pretty much all the server does is pull up user stats, and simply make an API or program that sends the user info when they sign up for the newsletter over to the email info server.

You could also probably rate limit this, it could get a little more complicated, but my basic implementation for this would be to make sweeping SQL queries whereby you allocate this program X MB of RAM, and this program simply loops and fills up it's RAM with SQL results (which would mean it needs a rough way of approximating the amount of RAM a query is going to take, and a way to know how many rows it got, or the next UID or something). The issue here is that you can't just grab all of them and retrieve the values from the query one at a time because that blocks the database.  You have to take all of it, or take what you want and close the query.

As far as making sure they don't get too many emails, daily is relatively easy, just make a column that is emails sent today, have the script check the number before it sends them an email, then make your fetch increment that value by 1 and away we go.  Then just make another script that resets those values to 0 at midnight.  For weekly and monthly, I wouldn't bother, those are going to be limited by the daily rate anyways, and you're going to have to track individual message dates to make sure you don't go over, it's just not worth it.

As far as people blocking you, you have more or less no control over that.  You shouldn't get blocked with an SES account, unless you're sending way too much spam.  If you do get blocked, there's really not much you can do about it, you've made it onto their banned list, and you'll more or less just have to deal with that.  You could send them nice letters, but I don't think they'll care much, they more or less get to do what they want.

Edit:  In response to your edit, if you truly have hundreds of thousands of users, you aren't going to want to use something premade.  If you're really talking about sending that many emails (with that many users, you'll be sending at least a hundred thousand emails a day), you're going to want to custom tailor something that's efficient for your setup, and setup up your SQL accordingly.  I don't know of any systems that will do that for you, but a basic setup wouldn't be too awful to do in some of the easier scripting languages, although obviously something compiled like C is going to run lighter on your system.

Comment: nice attempt to answer the OP's overly broad question - maybe he will see that the possible answers will elicit debate or are overly broad OR the base question of "give me a script that's already built" ultimately is a google search not a SO question. +1 for your effort

Comment: @Seth: Thank you for answering my question in the spirit it was presented. If SO had more users like you who understood what was being asked and were knowledgeable enough to answer it, rather than users that complain and downvote what they can't answer (instead of moving on to one they can) while spending more time in the comment section rather than answering questions, it would be a much more rewarding place. Regarding your edit, do you think something like phpList would not be adequate for the needs I presented? (I'm not very familiar with it but I've seen it recommended a few times here.)

Comment: According to the documentation [here](http://docs.phplist.com/PhpListConfigSendRate.html) you'll be able to send about 3,000 messages an hour with that.  Whether or not you'll actually be able to run that much depends on your hosting, that maths out to roughly 72,000 emails a day but that also doesn't account for bursts (i.e. everyone wakes up and goes to comment on someone's wall, so around 8am or something like that you'll need to send 30% of your days emails).  It can't hurt to try it, and 3,000 an hour is pretty good, to get much higher you'll need a language more suited for speed than PHP